# PHP time diffrence hourly competetion on site

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database

I am working on a small app in php using codeigniter.

App have a jquery countdown timer which countdown time left for current competition. Competition is hourly based and Gloabal(I am saying Global here to indicate that for everyone competition will finish at same time - Taking server time)

Here is logic I am using:

As competition is hourly and will be 24 competitions in a day. So what I am doing is: I made a timestamps field in database and updating (current timestamp + 1 hr) each hour using cron job. This time is end time of competition.

Then when user is going to app I am calling a function which getting competition end time and current time. Then getting difference of this time and time left i am putting in java script count downer to show time left.

Now problem:

Everthing is working fine except when time is at 12 to 1. Counter always shows negative time. Means time diffrece is coming to negative.

What I tried:

I tried to put

```
       date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

but no luck!

Here is my code:

```
$query="SELECT comp_end_time FROM competetions WHERE comp_type=1 ORDER BY comp_id DESC LIMIT 1";
$sql=mysql_query($query);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$end_time=strtotime($row['comp_end_time']);
$now=date("Y-m-d g:i:s");
$current_time=strtotime($now);
$time_diff=$end_time-$current_time;


$minutes=floor($time_diff / 60);
$sec = $time_diff - ($minutes * 60);
$minutes=(strlen($minutes) == 1) ? '0'.$minutes: $minutes;
$sec=(strlen($sec) == 1) ? '0'.$sec: $sec;

$min1=substr($minutes, 0, 1);
$min2=substr($minutes, 1, 2);
$sec1=substr($sec, 0, 1);
$sec2=substr($sec, 1, 2);

$data=array(
       'min1'=>$min1,
       'min2'=>$min2,
       'sec1'=>$sec1,
       'sec2'=>$sec2
       );
return $data;
}
```

And here is code to update time using cron:

```
function update_timer(){
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$now=date("Y-m-d g:i:s");
$currentTime=strtotime($now);
$timeAfterOneHour=$currentTime+60*60;
$new_hr=date("Y-m-d g:i:s",$timeAfterOneHour);
echo date("Y-m-d g:i:s",$currentTime).'<br>';
echo $new_hr;
mysql_query("UPDATE  `zaggora1_hotpant`.`competetions` SET  `comp_end_time` =  '$new_hr' WHERE  `competetions`.`comp_id` =1;");
}
```

Anybody know why time difference is coming negative? 
Any suggestion to use some different way to accomplish this task? Do i have to use codeigniter date helped etc?

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you aren't using CI's database class?

Comment: I am updating time from plain php file... as using cron

Comment: What is the data type of comp_end_time in mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things I would change:

```
$now=date("Y-m-d g:i:s");
$current_time=strtotime($now);
```

This can be reduced to simply:

```
$current_time = time();
```

For your cron script:

```
$now=date("Y-m-d g:i:s");
$currentTime=strtotime($now);
$timeAfterOneHour=$currentTime+60*60;
$new_hr=date("Y-m-d g:i:s",$timeAfterOneHour);
```

Can be changed to:

```
$currentTime = time();
$timeAfterOneHour=$currentTime+60*60;
$new_hr=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$timeAfterOneHour);
```

Notice the `H` instead of `g` in the `date()` format? That's because times are easier to compare if you use a 24hr clock with leading zeroes.